# Twoside memoir class

Tags: memoir, double-sided

I have a problem when I'm using twoside in memoir class numbers of pages on left side don't show. I don't why the top banner show number of subsection, too.

[Edit]
I would like to change headers. 
I'd like to have a only chapter title and number of page in header.
Beside I would like to start chapter in right side after printed. 
In this target I used [openleft], but I didn't reach it :C.

[edit 3]
How to change headers in odd pages? 
I like to show a number and title of chapter not paragraph.
Could you help me?

[Edit 2]

```
\documentclass[twoside, 12pt,a4paper, openright]{memoir}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}

\let\memoldbibsection\bibsection
\let\bibsection\relax
\usepackage[nobysame]{amsrefs}
\let\bibsection\memoldbibsection 


\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[right=2.7cm,left=3.5cm, top=2.7cm, bottom=2.5cm,includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{idxlayout}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}


\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
%\let\lll\relax


\makeindex


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}


\makeatletter

\renewcommand\PrintNames@a[4]{%
    \PrintSeries{\name}
        {#1}
        {}{ i \set@othername}
        {,}{ \set@othername}
        {}{ i \set@othername}
        {#2}{#4}{#3}%
}



%Rysunki w TikZ 
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

%Styl rozdzialow
\setlength\midchapskip{10pt}
\makechapterstyle{Vincent}{
\renewcommand\chapternamenum{}
\renewcommand\printchaptername{}
\renewcommand\chapnamefont{\Large\scshape}
\renewcommand\printchapternum{\chapnamefont \@chapapp \space \thechapter \centering}
\renewcommand\printchapternonum{\hrule\vskip\midchapskip}
\renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\Huge\scshape\centering}
\renewcommand\afterchapternum{\par\nobreak\vskip\midchapskip\hrule\vskip\midchapskip}
\renewcommand\afterchaptertitle{\par\vskip\midchapskip\hrule\nobreak\vskip\afterchapskip}
}

%Styl sekcji
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}
                                                                     {\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\large\scshape}}%\bfseries}}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}  
\setsecnumformat{\csname the#1\endcsname .\hspace{2.5mm}}

%headers

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}  
\setsecnumformat{\csname the#1\endcsname .\hspace{2.5mm}}
\setsecheadstyle{\large\scshape}
\setbeforesecskip{-3.5ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex}
\setaftersecskip{2.3ex plus.2ex}

\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\scshape\raggedright}
\setbeforesubsecskip{3.25ex plus1ex minus .2ex}
\setaftersubsecskip{-0.5em}

\makepagestyle{Ada}
\makeoddhead{Ada}{\scshape\rightmark}{}{\thepage}
\makeevenhead{Ada}{\thepage}{}{\scshape\leftmark}
\makeheadrule{Ada}{\textwidth}{0.5pt} %\headwidth
\makepsmarks{Ada}{%
  \createmark{chapter}{both}{nonumber}{}{}
  \createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
  \createplainmark{toc}{both}{\contentsname}
  \createplainmark{lof}{both}{\listfigurename}
  \createplainmark{lot}{both}{\listtablename}
  \createplainmark{bib}{both}{\bibname}
  \createplainmark{index}{both}{\indexname}
  \createplainmark{glossary}{both}{\glossaryname}
}



%Styl spisu treści
\renewcommand*{\cftchapteraftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterdotsep}{\@dotsep}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftchapterdotsep}}
\renewcommand*{\cftparskip}{2pt}
\makeatother

\chapterstyle{Vincent}
\pagestyle{Ada}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{empty}

%styl podpisu
\newcommand{\signaturespace}[2]{%
  % #1 = width of the dotted line
  % #2 = legend
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{cc}
  \hspace*{0pt}%
  \cleaders\hbox{\kern.1pt.\kern.1pt}\hskip#1\relax
  \hspace*{0pt}%
  \\[2pt]
  \scriptsize#2
  \end{tabular}%
  \endgroup
}

%indeks

\newtheoremstyle{bfnote}% name of the style to be used.
{9pt}% measure of space to leave above the theorem.
{9pt}% measure of space to leave below the theorem.
{}% name of font to use in the body of the theorem.
{}% measure of space to indent.
{\bfseries}% name of head font.
{\\}% punctuation between head and body.
{0.5em}% space after theorem head; " " = normal interword space.
{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ #3}}% manually specify head.

\theoremstyle{bfnote}
\newtheorem{definicja}{Definicja}[section]
\newtheorem{przyklad}{Przykład}[section]
\newtheorem{oznaczenie}{Oznaczenie}
\newtheorem{wlasnosc}{Własność}[section]
\newtheorem{wlasnosci}{Własności}[section]
\newtheorem{uwaga}{Uwaga}[chapter]


\theoremstyle{bfnote}
\newtheorem{twierdzenie}{Twierdzenie}[section]
\newtheorem{lemat}{Lemat}[section]
\newtheorem{wniosek}{Wniosek}[chapter]
\newtheorem{stwierdzenie}{Stwierdzenie}[chapter]



\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\hspace\labelsep #1}

\newcommand*\lowercasecapitals[1]{\MakeLowercase{\large\scshape#1}}
\setsecheadstyle{\lowercasecapitals}

%dowód od nowej lini 
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\mbox{}\\*
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother




\begin{document}


\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\include{Oswiadczenie}


\clearpage
\tableofcontents*

%Wcięcie akapitowe 
\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}

%sybmol stopnia 
\newcommand{\degre}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}





\begin{document}


\chapter{Etapy rozwiązywania zadań konstrukcyjnych}
\indent Starożytni greccy matematycy w poszukiwaniu rozwiązania zadania konstrukcyjnego stworzyli schemat rozwiązania i analizy. Zapoczątkowana przez słynną szkołę platońską, a dalej kontynuowana przez Euklidesa, metoda opierała się na~wykonaniu czterech kroków: analizy zadania, opisu konstrukcji, dowodu poprawności oraz~badaniu liczby rozwiązań i warunków istnienia. Każdy z tych etapów, w sposób istotny, jest nieodłącznym elementem rozwiązania zadania konstrukcyjnego i tylko razem mogą dać pełen obraz zagadnienia. \cite[zob.][str.~68]{Doman}

\section{Analiza zadania}
\indent Jest to niewątpliwie jeden z ważniejszych etapów rozwiązania zadania konstrukcyjnego, bowiem to właśnie na~tym etapie zakładamy, że szukaną figurę można skonstruować. Wykorzystując jej własności poszukujemy istotnych związków między danymi a nowo powstałymi punktami, prostymi czy okręgami, które pozwolą na~wykreślenie poszukiwanej figury. \\
\indent Powyższe postępowanie jest procesem mającym na celu znalezienie konceptu, który pozwoli na~rozwiązanie zadania. Pomocne przy realizacji tego kroku jest~wykonanie rysunku pomocniczego. \cite[zob.][str.~69]{Doman}

\section{Opis konstrukcji}
\indent W tym kroku podajemy ciąg konstrukcji podstawowych, czyli takich, które~można wykonać przy pomocy z~góry określonych przyrządów konstrukcyjnych. Ów~opis powinien opierać się o obiekty matematyczne podane w treści zadania lub~wykreślone w trakcie jego rozwiązywania. W efekcie finalnym żądamy, aby został podany ciąg instrukcji mający na~celu doprowadzenie do skonstruowania szukanej figury. Należy pamiętać, aby opis ten był bardzo ścisły i~nie~dawał możliwości innej interpretacji, niż ta która została podana przez twórcę zadania. \cite[zob.][str.~69]{Doman}

\section{Dowód poprawności konstrukcji}
Następny etap ma na celu weryfikację poprawności przeprowadzonej konstrukcji. W tym kroku sprawdzamy, czy~figura powstała w~wyniku wykonania czynności określonych w opisie konstrukcji spełnia warunki zadania. \cite[zob.][str.~69]{Doman}

\section{Badanie warunków istnienia i liczby rozwiązań}
Ostatnim elementem rozwiązania zadania konstrukcyjnego jest sprawdzenie tzw.~warunków istnienia, czyli określenie, czy~z~danych występujących w treści zadania można faktycznie skonstruować wymaganą figurę. Ponadto, należy przeprowadzić analizę liczby (ilości) rozwiązań. Jeśli obiektu nie można skonstruować, to~liczba możliwych konstrukcji wynosi zero. Z drugiej strony istnieją obiekty, które~można skonstruować na nieskończenie wiele sposobów, np. istnieje nieskończenie wiele prostych równoległych do danej prostej. \cite[zob.][str.~69]{Doman}

\section{Przykład}
Dane są dwa różne punkty $A, B$, odcinki o długości $a, b$ oraz niech $|AB|=c$, przy~czym $c$ jest najdłuższym z~podanych odcinków. Skonstruować trójkąt o bokach długości $a, b, c$. \\
Rozwiązanie: 
\begin{enumerate}

    \item Analiza zadania: \\
Przypuśćmy, że istnieje trójkąt $\vartriangle ABC$ o bokach długości $|AB|=c$, $|AC|=b$, $|BC|=a$.

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(1,0.5) rectangle (10,5.7);
\draw (2.,1.)-- (9.,1.);
\draw (9.,1.)-- (3.,5.);
\draw (3.,5.)-- (2.,1.);
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=black] (2.,1.) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (1.5,1) node {\begin{large} $A$ \end{large}};
\draw [fill=black] (9.,1.) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (9.3,1) node {\begin{large} $B$ \end{large}};
\draw [fill=black] (3.,5.) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (3,5.5) node {\begin{large} $C$ \end{large}};
\draw[color=black] (5.6,0.77) node {\begin{large} $c$ \end{large}};
\draw[color=black] (6,3.25) node {\begin{large} $a$ \end{large}};
\draw[color=black] (2.23,3.25) node {\begin{large} $b$ \end{large}};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

Należy zauważyć, że odległość punktu $C$ od punktu $A$ wynosi $b$ oraz odległość punktu $C$ od punktu $B$ wynosi $a$, stąd punkt $C$ jest punktem wspólnym okręgów: $\mathcal{O_A}(A, b)$ oraz $\mathcal{O_B}(B, a)$. W ten sposób znaleźliśmy zależność między punktami i odcinkami zadanymi w zadaniu a punktem $C$. 

    \item Opis konstrukcji:
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
\item \label{konst1} Kreślimy okrąg $\mathcal{O_A}(A, b)$ o środku w punkcie $A$ i promieniu $b$,
\item \label{konst2} Kreślimy okrąg $\mathcal{O_B}(B, a)$ o środku w punkcie $B$ i promieniu $a$,
\item \label{konst3} Wyznaczamy punkty wspólne $C, D$ okręgów $\mathcal{O_A}$ oraz $\mathcal{O_B}$ (o ile istnieją),
\item Kreślimy odcinki $[AD], [BD]$ oraz $[AC], [BC]$,
\item Trójkąty $\vartriangle ABC$ oraz $\vartriangle ABD$ mają boki o długościach: $a, b, c$.
\end{enumerate}

    \item Dowód poprawności: \\
Konstrukcja jest poprawna, ponieważ trójkąt można skonstruować wtedy i~tylko wtedy, gdy suma długości dwóch krótszych boków jest większa od~długości najdłuższego boku. 

    \item Badanie istnienia i liczby rozwiązań: \\
Konstrukcje \ref{konst1} oraz \ref{konst2} są wykonalne dla dowolnych danych wynikających z~treści zadania.\\
Konstrukcja \ref{konst3} jest wykonalna, gdy istnieje dwuelementowy przekrój okręgów $\mathcal{O_A}(A, b)$ oraz $\mathcal{O_B}(B, a)$. Warunek ten jest spełniony, gdy odległość środków okręgów jest mniejsza od sumy długości promieni. Wówczas zachodzi nierówność $c = \vert AB \vert < a + b$, zwana także nierównością trójkąta. W pozostałych przypadkach nie jest możliwe skonstruowanie trójkąta. \\
W wyniku wyżej opisanej konstrukcji otrzymujemy dwa trójkąty, które spełniają warunki zadania. 

\end{enumerate}





%Wcięcie akapitowe 
\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}

%sybmol stopnia 
\newcommand{\degre}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are not using two side, you explicitly use `oneside` in this example. Also **always** make your examples complete. Plus why are you redefining `\section`?

Comment: Sorry, I copied worng.

Comment: Can you please make your example compilable? I get errors about `You can't use \spacefactor in vertical mode. \section`. I guess there is something fishy with your section redefinition. You should tackle this problem first before wondering why the output might not as you expect it. If you ignore errors anything can happen in the broken file you mistake for a pdf.

Comment: Also this is just the preamble without any actual document to reproduce your problem. Please have a look at [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: (1) you do realize you only defined a header for the right (odd) header?  You have not specified anything for the even one, thus it is empty. (2) Memoir has interfaces for setting space above and below and setting the fonts for `\section` and friends, no need to manually redefine

Comment: (1b) also you never defined what section should write to the header

Comment: (1c) may I ask why some paragraphs start with `\indent` and others does not?

Comment: @ago I didn't write this preambole I've got it as tamplate. 
I'm not professionalist and I couln't do it :c

Comment: @Blazej If you want to spare yourself a considerable amount of pain, don't use this template - it seems to be a big mess!

Comment: @daleif Do want to write an answer? I would then delete mine, yours will certainly be much better.

Comment: On the other side this tamplate look pretty good. 
Could you give me a favour what I should change?

Comment: @samcarter added something a little more extensive, just a little

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some replacements that you might want to use. I agree with samcarter, this template is a huge mess. Especially because the one who made it did not document it.

## Sections

```
% this redefinition of \thesection is actually the default      
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}  
% how the section number is written in \section, it calls \thesection
\setsecnumformat{\csname the#1\endcsname .\hspace{2.5mm}}
% font for \section, might want to add \raggedright
\setsecheadstyle{\large\scshape}
% space above, negative spaces have special meaning, here, see the memoir manual 
\setbeforesecskip{-3.5ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex}
% similar for space below 
\setaftersecskip{2.3ex plus.2ex}
```

Similar for subsecion, but without comments

```
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\scshape\raggedright}
\setbeforesubsecskip{3.25ex plus1ex minus .2ex}
\setaftersubsecskip{-0.5em}
```

## Headers

This is more of a memoir way of doing headers and footers

```
\makepagestyle{Ada}
\makeoddhead{Ada}{\scshape\rightmark}{}{\thepage}
\makeevenhead{Ada}{\thepage}{}{\scshape\leftmark}
\makeheadrule{Ada}{\textwidth}{0.5pt} %\headwidth
\makepsmarks{Ada}{%
  \createmark{chapter}{both}{nonumber}{}{}
  \createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
  \createplainmark{toc}{both}{\contentsname}
  \createplainmark{lof}{both}{\listfigurename}
  \createplainmark{lot}{both}{\listtablename}
  \createplainmark{bib}{both}{\bibname}
  \createplainmark{index}{both}{\indexname}
  \createplainmark{glossary}{both}{\glossaryname}
}
```

I suggest you replace the related stuff in your template with the code above.

I'm pretty sure you can configure memoir so you do not need the `indentfirst` package, though I have not looked further into this (had a look into `indentfirst`, it is sumper simple and non intrusive, and can be used just fine).

One extra advice: Never, ever use `\\` in the text. You never need a manual line break in the text. Always use a new paragraph.

Comment: Thanks but I really start doing it od begining

Comment: How to change position on page number?

Comment: @Blazej please be more specific

Comment: I use \documentclass[twoside, 12pt,a4paper, leftopen]{memoir}
because I need to start chapter on right side after printed, but in this version the numbers od pages are inside book, not outside. 

Also I added pohot

Comment: @Blazej Update the code you posted with my code above. Then explain exactly what it is you want. It is not clear from your drawing. What goes where? What exactly goes on a left hand (even) page and what goes on the right as long as you are not specific, who are we going to help? And please update the question instead of writing details in comments. Also there is nothing called leftopen. And openleft does not give you chapter start on right hand pages, memoir default does. Details details details

Comment: Almost I'm  finishing but on odd page in headers I would like to have a title of chapter not section.

Comment: @Blazej and what should go on even headers? (traditionally in most traditions in Western Europe, the chapter title go on the even header, left hand page)

Comment: I know, but I need just chapter title on both side.
My thesis is too short to include section title in headers

Comment: @Blazej then just use the same mark in both and perhaps remove the section mark from via `\clearmark{section}` after `\pagestyle{Ada}`